# Most Efficient way to compare large 'text' type values in MySQL using InnoDB engine

Tags: mysql, text, blob, innodb, query-performance

I have a staging table like this :

```
CREATE TABLE `staging` (
  `created_here_at` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `desc_text`  TEXT NOT NULL );
```

And destination table as :

```
CREATE TABLE `final_tbl` (
  `row_id` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created_here_at` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `desc_text`  TEXT NOT NULL );
```

I want to insert desc_text into final_tbl only if it is not present. I am thinking of two options :

1. check if staging.desc_text exists in final_tbl.desc_text, if not then insert into final_tbl
2. Maintain a column in 'final_tbl' that will store the SHA224 value of desc_text column. compare SHA224 value of staging.desc_text with SHA224 column in final table and then decide whether to insert or ignore.

I want to know which option will be faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm . . .

Create the SHA224 column, with an index:

```
create index unq_final_tbl_sha224 on final_tbl(sha224);
```

Then do an update like this:

```
insert into final_tbl(desc_text, sha224)
    select *
    from (select desc_text, sha224
          from staging s
          where not exists (select 1 from final_tbl f where f.ssh224 = s.ssh224)
         ) s
    where not exists (select 1 from final_tbl f where f.desc_text = s.desc_text);
```

The idea behind the subquery is to be absolutely sure that MySQL doesn't get any ideas about comparing the long form of the field before comparing the hash value.  It is probably safe to use `and` without the subquery, but the above is more conservative.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, Instead of your suggestion, if I use " insert ignore into final_tbl ( desc_text, sha224 ) select desc_text, sha224 from staging " . While inserting records into final_tbl, won't mysql first check the unique key column and decide right after, instead of comparing 'desc_text' column?

Comment: @abb . . . I was thinking of something similar, but if you have two *different* `desc_text` values with the same sha224 value, then the second will not be inserted.  Such a hashing collision is rather rare, but not impossible.

Comment: Even for the relatively short MD5, the is only one chance in 9 trillion that there will be a false hit like that with 9 trillion documents.

Comment: Good point @RickJames , Chances are even rare with SHA2. It is a negligible risk to depend on unique key of generated by SHA2.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL 5.7 supports generated columns.

Create a SHA-512 hash field on desc_text:

```
ALTER TABLE final_tbl ADD sha512 AS SHA2(desc_text, 512);
```

and add a unique index on it:

```
ALTER TABLE final_tbl ADD UNIQUE (sha512);
```

Then on a duplicate hash you'll get an error:

```
mysql> insert into final_tbl(desc_text) values('aaa');
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry 'd6f644b19812e97b5d871658d6d3400ecd4787faeb9b8990c1e7608288664be7' for key 'sha512'
```